# Prove $S\cap S ^\bot=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of the inner product space $V$ and $S^\bot$ be the orthogonal complement of $S$.

Prove $S\cap S ^\bot=\{0\}$

Comment: Is $S$ just a subset? Because the result is wrong in this case: just take $S$ to be the empty set.

Comment: My bad its an orthonormal basis of V

Comment: It is still false when $S$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ (or any basis).

Comment: Oh I was right the first time haha but may I ask why it would be false? Is there a S$^\bot$ for an orthonormal basis since its elements are all orthogonal to one another?

Comment: If $S = \emptyset$ for example, then $S \cap S^\bot = \emptyset$, not equal to $\{0\}$. More generally, $S \cap S^\bot \subset \{0\}$, with equality iff $0 \in S$.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in "nonempty" so that everyone can get over it and save space in the comments for actually productive comments.

Comment: Even if $S$ is nonempty, $S\cap S^\bot$ may be empty since $S$ is just a set but not a sub vector space.

Comment: @Joe If $S$ is any basis then $S^\perp$ only contains the zero vector.  It has nothing to do with it being orthonormal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $s\in S$ is also in $S^{\perp}$ then by definition $\langle s, r\rangle=0$ for all $r\in S.$ Then taking $r=s$ gives $s=0.$

Comment: This makes sense, but why are we just allowed to set r=s? Is it because you are claiming this element of S,r, can be equivalent to the intersection because ambiguity?

Comment: This answer does not lack clarity.  Please expand on your request.

Comment: @Joe If something is true for all $r \in S$ then it remains true when we fix $r$ to be anything in $S$.  $s$ is one of those things.  The second half of your comment is not recognizable English.

Comment: @EricWong Sorry about that, trying to think, type, and write. Actually you answered my second part with your last comment. It makes total sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint $\langle x, x\rangle >0$ if $x\ne 0$.